# Group by operation using one of arrays' values

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have array of arrays in `javascript` that looks like: `[[1, 23.34, -5.22], [1, 2.34, -52.22], [2, 0.34, -5.02], ...]`. I need to `group by` by the first number in the arrays and produce 2 different ouputs:

1. Object (`key: 2D array`) that looks like this:

   ```
   {1: [[23.34, -5.22], [2.34, -52.22]],
    2: [[0.34, -5.02], ...],
    ...}
   ```
2. 3D array that would just signify the grouping:

   ```
   [[[23.34, -5.22], [2.34, -52.22]], [[0.34, -5.02], ...], ...]
   ```

I want to use `ES6`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try something yourself? Add that code as well.

Comment: I did, but I just do not know how to approach the problem in native JavaScript. It feels like I need to use reduce function but I am not sure how

Comment: Read about reduce [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). I don't see any application in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout this code

```js
let array = [[1, 23.34, -5.22], [1, 2.34, -52.22], [2, 0.34, -5.02]];

let obj = {};

array.forEach(subArray =>
{
    let key = subArray[0];
    if(!obj[key])
        obj[key] = [];
    subArray.splice(0,1);
    obj[key].push(subArray);
});

console.log(obj);

let keys = Object.keys(obj);
let array3D = [];
keys.forEach(key => {
    array3D.push(obj[key])
});

console.log(array3D);
```

Comment: Your use of `map` here tends to be confusing. While `.map()` is slightly fewer characters, what you are actually using it for is equivalent to `.forEach()`. The primary thing that you are doing by posting an Answer is answering a question which is asking how to do something (i.e. you are helping people learn how to do something). Thus, being clear is *significantly* more important than saving a whopping  8 (2*4) characters (or just trying to be clever, or doing code golf on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Makyen thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 1):

There's already a answer which uses `map` method but I find using `forEach` in this case more appropriate.

```js
const a = [
  [1, 23.34, -5.22], [1, 2.34, -52.22], [2, 0.34, -5.02]
];

let b = {};
let c = [];

a.forEach(x=>{
  if(!b[x[0]]){
    b[x[0]] = [];
  }
  b[x[0]].push(x.slice(1));
});
console.log(b);

Object.values(b).forEach(x => c.push(x));
console.log(c);
```